# Running one file on multiple servers

Tags: java, deployment, environment-variables

Right now my team deals with about 4-5 different servers and about 2-3 different DB servers and we're using environmental variables to decide which server we're on and what server configuration to use.

Is there a better way to do this as my team continues to expand?  I've considered compiler flags / args, but it doesn't seem as robust.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my perspective, in java, you have basically 3 ways to crack this cookie:

1. Environment variables
2. -D JVM parameters (which are System Properties)
3. properties files

You've already discovered Environment Variables and that is pretty much "the unix way" to get the effect you are after; different configuration to common binary that customizes the running application for the environment it is executing on.

System Properties are really the Java "moral equivalent" of Environment Variables.  They come in via -D parameters on your application's command line like...

```
java -Dlogback.configurationFile=/opt/dm/logback.xml -cp app.jar org.rekdev.App
```

Explicit Properties file processing http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/properties.html in Java is a third variant which you often see coupled with -D to get something like default behavior which can be overridden at runtime from the command line.  That is what is basically going on with the logback.xml configuration above, the JAR file has a logback.xml inside it that will be used unless a System Property called "logback.configurationFile" exists, at which point the App will load it instead.

As you try to figure out how to keep this all in sync and working correctly in a multi-server environment, consider the use of chef http://wiki.opscode.com/display/chef/Home to do the deployments and put each specific environment's customizations under chefs control.  Put the chef "recipes" in version control and, voila, full on configuration management.

SHIP IT!

Answer (score 0):

I can see two scenarios

1. You embed all the different properties within your package (can be a war, ear, jar, or on the file system `/yourapp/etc/`)
2. You embed only one property file and this one is created during build (with ant or maven)

Say your app is named `foo`

**Solution 1**

It has the advantage that your app can be put as-is on any of the supported servers (all that have a property file in your app package).
Your properties will be named `foo.dev.properties`, `foo.test.properties`, `foo.prod.properties`, `foo.damien.properties`, `foo.bob.properties`.

One other advantage is that every developer working has its own dev file that he can safely push on svn/git/whatever and be sure that other developer won't destroy his config.

At runtime the application can check the `-D` parameter or even retrieve the hostname dinamycally, in order to load the correct property file.

**Solution 2**

It has the advantage that your package is not polluted by unnecessary properties files.

You must configure a lot of ant tasks/maven target in order to build for specific environment. You will have in your source directory the properties files for the environments also, but only one will be shipped with your app. This one `foo.properties` will only have placeholders for values, and values will be inferred within it using `foo.ENV.properties` with the right ant task/maven target.

At my actual job and the previous one also, we did use the solution 1, I think it brings flexibility.
Some parameter (like database user/password) were fetched directly from environment variables on the Unix servers though (so that only the server admins knew the credentials).

You can safely mix the solutions, in order to get where you feel there is the more flexibility for you and your team.